# Issue on Submit Action for Sitecore Forms in NextJS app

Tags: sitecore-forms, nextjs, jss-forms

I'm trying to implement `Sitecore Forms` with the `NextJS` app using this official document https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/implement-a-sitecore-form-in-a-jss-next-js-app.html

Since I'm using next js I'm passing `sitecoreApiHost={''}` as mentioned in the document.

[image]

I have also followed this document to create Sitecore Form, created rendering, and added the same on the sample page;
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--using-a-sitecore-form-in-jss-applications.html

To simplify I have just added a redirect to the page as an action on Submit button with a couple of input boxes.

[image]

When the new rendering is added to the page for forms and after publishing I'm getting the following error;

> **'Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON'**

[image]

Appreciate any help on this topic, thank you.

Comment: Can you check `Console` what are the other errors logged?

Comment: Just 404 not found and 'Form submit error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON'

Comment: I assume that you are seeing that error because Forms is trying to parse the 404 HTML document as a JSON (since it expects a JSON, not a 404 html response). What happens if you instead use “Save Data” as a submit action?

Comment: Even 'Save Data' gives the same result.

Comment: I followed the same, added the serverSideRenderingEngineEditOnly="false" sitecore.javascriptservices.app.config and in one more config. and also added the patch of HeadlessSiteAccess processor after TransferRoutedRequest. I am still getting the same error "**Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**" in form submit. Console Error:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MWbg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MWbg.png) Please share any advice on it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution which is mentioned here;

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002853

Basically, for the newly created app, one more config needs to be added which is `serverSideRenderingEngineEditOnly="false"` and done.

Check the `showconfig.aspx` for the above key.